# Integrating Spree into existing Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

I had an existing Rails app with my models and controllers, but I wanted to put an e-commerce integration in it.

So, I installed Spree gem, and it worked fine.

The thing is, Spree cart + login etc won't work on the first app, and vice verse.

Should I move all of my controllers + models inside Spree and make a full Spree App with my other views?

Or should I integrate Spree features (cart...login...etc) into my first app?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably best if you try to integrate Spree into your existing App.  If you have your own User models, you can just tell Spree about it and use that.

All the details on how to do this is in the Developer Guide:
https://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/authentication.html

Comment: But, for example, If I want to put the cart in my views (which don't belong to spree), is it possible? @natsumi